# Starting a fragement is restarting the parent fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-places-api

I am showing google maps in a fragement with the auto complete search bar on the same scree. My xml layout looks like that

```
<LinearLayout ..>
    <Fragment .../> // the map fragment
    <Fragment .../>  // the auto complete support fragment
</LinearLayout>
```

When you click on the AutoCompleteSupportFragment search bar, it opens overlay window so you can do your search. Once you backout of it, I noticed from the log that the MAP fragment is restarting (OnCreate and OnCreateView are called again).

It is as if showing nested fragment is reseting the parent fragment. This is a problem as whatever information I have are lost and I  can't send the selected place from the bar back to the map

Any help?

PS: There is no code to add the nested fragment. The fragments are google fragments and defined in XML.

Comment: You should be able to use `onSavedInstanceState` to maintain the state and the data.

Comment: It is not about maintaining, the issue here is that why the fragment is restarting in the first place. I need to pass the selected place to map fragement so it navigates to it, and if the map fragement is destroyed then that's an issue.  I am just wondering how map fragement with search fragement coexist.

Comment: It's "restarting" because that is how the lifecycle of a fragment works. You should consider other options, like using something like a toolbar (or other view) for your search. Here is the fragment link https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments . It will show you why your fragment restarts.

Comment: Then how does the map fragement and the autocomplete fragment ( both widgets provided by good) work togther and don't restart when you do searches?

Comment: Maybe you're implementing it wrong. https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete and who said that they don't restart?

Comment: Even if I don't do a search, just clicking on the AutoComplete Fragment starts its search fragment which results in the map fragment going through initialization again when you come back to it

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using `PlaceSelectionListener`, which might look something like this:

```
// Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);

// Specify the types of place data to return.
autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));

// Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the response.
autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
        Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Status status) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
        Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
    }
});
```

You can find this example and other examples of how to properly implement this in the [documents](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete).

Comment: This is exactly what I use. as soon as you click on the R.id.autocomplete_fragment widget and then select place (or cancel) then the map fragement gets recreated

Comment: @Snake did you manage to find a work around for this problem?

Comment: I had to store the value in sharepreferences and retreive it while making sure it is not valid beyon this activity. Very convoluted solution that I am sure is not the right way to do it

Comment: That isn't the correct way to do this. Honestly, the docs say, "To receive a notification when the user has selected a place, your app should override the activity's onActivityResult(), checking for the request code you have passed for your intent, as shown in the following example.". The docs clearly outline 2 ways to do this.

Comment: @BlackHatSaumari, I don't think you are getting the issue here. Whatever the docs says, is implemented. The issue here is that you have map fragment and on top of it you have AutoCompleteSupportFragement (completely different fragment).  Let's say in the map fragement you moved the map around to some location and zoomed in. Then you click on search bar (the auto complete). For simplicty don't even do a search, just cancel the search. You will find that the map fragement has reseted back to the orginal location/zoom level. The whole map fragement got recreated

Comment: The reason this is an issue is because if you do a search and select a place, how can you move the map to that place? The map fragement is getting recreated and you are losing your data

Comment: You recreate the map with the location you get from the search. Seems pretty straight forward. When you do the search, you send the data from the search back tot the map and rebuild it. Furthermore, if you are worried about just storing the data if a user cancels the search then you would retain the state via `onSavedInstanceState`. What bothers me is your comment " Whatever the docs says, is implemented. " This tells me you haven't even looked at the docs. There are 2 options for implementing this, not one. At the end of the day, the activity is going to be rebuilt. You need to handle it.